# Domain registration - Does the registrar matter?

Tags: domain-registration

I have following questions about domain name registration:
1: Will it matter, in technical aspect, with whom I register my domain? I know for webhosting there are lot of things to consider e.g. uptime/support/etc.

2: What impact do I have if I transfer domain from one registrar to another?

Comment: The difference will be with the pricing and the support that you will receive. Check out this domain registrar review: https://medium.com/@JohnBeardslee/best-domain-name-registrars-top-recommendations-b3d65128b46a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical difference in the name registration.  All domain names are ultimately stored in the central name repositories.  So there is no difference in uptime or whatever.

The differences in registrars come down to things like service, services (do they provide their own dns hosting, private registration, etc..) and price.

Service wise, you need to look at their policies in the event you let your domain expire and want to get it back (maybe you forgot to renew it), and how much that costs.

As for transfer, you pay a fee for the transfer.  The impact is that it takes some time to perform.

Comment: An additional impact of a transfer is that usually one year is added to the life of the domain.

Comment: @Rincewind42 true in gTLDs (but you also have the rule that the expiration can not be more than 10 years in the future and most ccTLDs but there are exceptions doing no change in expiration after a transfer.